# Three.js - determine if points are co-planar and mapping co-planar points onto XY plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Given a set of Vector3 points, I need to test if they are co-planar in some arbitrary plane. Assuming they are co-planar I then need to map/project them onto the XY plane while retaining the scale between all the points.

I don't think the math for this is *too* hard but am looking for a simple/effective way to do it using three.js...

Comment: One way to test if the set of points is co-planar would be to take the first three points and use `Plane.setFromCoPlanarPoints(p1, p2, p3)` to make a plane. Then for subsequent points use `Plane.distanceToPoint(p)`. Is this an efficient way to do the first part I wonder?

Answer (score 3):

1. Function for verifying that the four points lie in the same plane is [very simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330360):

```js
function tripleProduct(a,b,c) {
  return a.clone().dot(
    b.clone().cross(c)
  );
}
    
function _isCoPlanar(a,b,c,d) {
  var ab = b.clone().sub(a);
  var ac = c.clone().sub(a);
  var ad = d.clone().sub(a);
  return tripleProduct(ab,ac,ad) === 0;
}
```

[You need to go through the array](https://jsfiddle.net/avyvmvL0/), and make sure that every point since the fourth lies in the same plane with the first three points.

2. For projection on the plane you can use the [`projectOnPlane`](https://threejs.org/docs/api/math/Vector3.html#projectOnPlane) function.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have an arbitrary number of points to check, so I can't use your solution directly but am sure I could adapt it. Is it likely to be faster than approach I suggested in comment of finding an initial plane and using `distanceTo` on subsequent points?

Comment: @jugglingcats I think this is more accurate than the method proposed by you. Look at the link to `jsfiddle` - there an example for a large number of points.

Comment: Regarding `projectOnPlane`, it does not give the desired results in this case. For example, consider the points `[(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,0,1),(0,0,1)]`, ie. a square in the XZ plane. If we project these onto the XY plane it gives points on a line: `[(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,0)]`. The intention is to transform the square/co-planar points onto the XY plane (or any plane parallel to XY) while maintaining the shape.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fiddle link!

Comment: The approach I'm considering for the second part is to find the angle and an axis of rotation for the points, and then use `Vector3.applyAxisAngle`. To do this I'm using the normal to XY plane `(0,0,1)` and the plane constructed from the points. Then `z_normal=new Vector3(0,0,1)`,  `angle=plane.normal.angleTo(z_normal)` and `axis=new Vector3().crossVectors(plane.normal, z_normal)`

Comment: @jugglingcats Then it is not a projection. It is a combination of translate and two rotations.

Comment: Why two rotations?

Comment: @jugglingcats Around X and around Y.